# Persist Material-UI Selections With Redux Data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, material-ui, react-hooks

I'm trying to implement a Material-UI Select component with data from Redux, to allow the selections to persist across refreshes.

I've got two arrays of data inside of Redux: the `sourceTags` array, which is my list of clickable menu options, and my `selectedTags` array, which includes the selected options (those the user has clicked). The api for the Material-UI component is [here](https://material-ui.com/api/select/).

The component looks like this:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Select, Input, MenuItem } from "@material-ui/core";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { setTags } from "../actions/search";

const MultiChipSelect = ({ source }) => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const selectedTags = useSelector(state => state.search.tags);
    const sourceTags = useSelector(state => state.settings[source].tags);

    const handleTagClick = async (e) => {
        dispatch(setTags(e.target.value)); // Sets my searchTags list in Redux.
        // The e.target.value is an array of objects, or an empty array.

    };

    return (
        <Select
        multiple
        value={selectedTags}
        onChange={handleTagClick}
        input={<Input id="select-multiple" />}
        >
        {sourceTags.map(val => (
            <MenuItem key={val._id} value={val}>
            {val.data}
            </MenuItem>
        ))}
        </Select>
    );
}

export default MultiChipSelect;
```

The component works, at least partially. Here's what it looks like when I make a selection:

[image]

The redux store is also updating correctly. Happy to share the action generator and reducer but that's not the problem.

The problem is, when I refresh the page, the selectedTags array does not display in the component. The objects do appear inside the select component, but aren't showing up:

[image]

**How can I restructure this Material-UI component to pull in data from my Redux store correctly, and persist the displayed selection across refreshes, rather than relying on the `useState` hook that does not, as per the examples?**

For context, here's what one would look like using the `useState` hook. Keep in mind that this doesn't persist the selections across refreshes:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Select, Input, MenuItem } from "@material-ui/core";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

const MultiChipSelect = ({ source }) => {

    const sourceTags = useSelector(state => state.settings[source].tags);
    const [tags, setTags] = useState([]);

    const handleTagClick = async (e) => {
        setTags(e.target.value); // Sets my tags list.
    };

    return (
        <Select
        multiple
        value={tags}
        onChange={handleTagClick}
        input={<Input id="select-multiple" />}
        >
        {sourceTags.map(val => (
            <MenuItem key={val._id} value={val}>
            {val.data}
            </MenuItem>
        ))}
        </Select>
    );
}

export default MultiChipSelect;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

Turns out, the component was actually receiving the information correctly, but that it was not displaying it because it was using the default render function.

I needed to replace the render function with one that would use the data from the object. The fixed component looks like this:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Select, Input, MenuItem } from "@material-ui/core";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { setTags } from "../actions/search";

const MultiChipSelect = ({ source }) => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const selectedTags = useSelector(state => state.search.tags);
    const sourceTags = useSelector(state => state.settings[source].tags);

    const handleTagClick = async (e) => {
        dispatch(setTags(e.target.value));
    };

    return (
        <Select
        multiple
        value={selectedTags}
        onChange={handleTagClick}
        input={<Input id="select-multiple" />}
        // renderValue={selected => ( // This function is necessary when using objects, because the 'label' value should display the value.data value, not just the object. This is necessary because I'm using objects instead of strings.
        //    <div>
        //      {selected.map(value => (
        //        <Chip key={value._id} label={value.data}/>
        //      ))}
        //    </div>
        //  )}
        >
        >
        {sourceTags.map(val => (
            <MenuItem key={val._id} value={val}>
            {val.data}
            </MenuItem>
        ))}
        </Select>
    );
}

export default MultiChipSelect;
```